# Error in event creation using MySQL

Tags: mysql

Am using the below code to create an EVENT in MYSQL. In this time i want to drop and create a table using a query.

```
Drop  Event  if exists EVT_UP_TIMESHEET;
CREATE EVENT EVT_UP_TIMESHEET
  ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' Day
  STARTS '2012-08-01 12:00:00'
DO

  Drop table if exists tbl_temp;

 create table tbl_temp as ( SELECT e.userid            AS Employee_ID,

       e.memo              AS Employee_Name,
   e.Department        AS Department,
.....
```

It returns the following error:

> ERROR : Table tbl_temp already exists.

Please help me to do this.

Comment: Try to call just `DROP TABLE ..` and look if it will be dropped.

Comment: yes when i execute the drop comment the table dropped successfully.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a workaround - try to use [TRUNCATE TABLE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html) and [INSERT...SELECT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) statements instead of DROP/CREATE TABLE.

Comment: I have encounter the new error index i_emp_temp is already exists "create index i_emp_tmp on tbl_temp (employee_id,punchdate);"

Comment: Create table with all its indexes once. And do not change table structure from the event.

Comment: K i accept this. But the table doesn't truncate.Records inserted double time.

Comment: Hm, it looks like a MySQL bug.

Answer (score 1):

Use `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tbl_temp` instead of `create table tbl_temp`

Or to delete the table you can use [`TRUNCATE TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/truncate-table.html) instead of `DROP TABLE` and to create you can use [`INSERT...SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-select.html) instead of `CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: I want to drop that table every day and create again.